# Fitting Neural Net with different Epoch number in a loop without starting over each time

Tags: python, loops, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am fitting a recurrent neural net in `python` using `keras` library. I am fitting the model with different `epoch` number by changing parameter `nb_epoch` in `Sequential.fit()` function. Currently I'm using `for` loop which starts over fitting each time I change `nb_epoch` which is lots of repeating work. Here is my code (the loop is in the bottom of the code, if you want to skip other parts of the code details):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve


####################################
###
### Here I do the data processing to create trainX, testX
###
####################################

#model create:
model = Sequential()

#this is the epoch array for different nb_epoch


####################################
###
### Here I define model architecture
###
####################################

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")


#################################################
####  Defining arrays for different epoch number 
#################################################
epoch_array = range(100, 2100,100)


# I create the following arrays/matrices to store the result of NN fit 
# different epoch number.

train_DBN_fitted_Y = np.zeros(shape=(len(epoch_array),trainX.shape[0]))
test_DBN_fitted_Y = np.zeros(shape=(len(epoch_array),testX.shape[0]))

###############################################
###
### Following loop is the heart of the question
###
##############################################

i = 0  
for epoch in epoch_array:
      model.fit( trainX, trainY,
            batch_size = 16, nb_epoch = epoch, validation_split = 0.05, verbose = 2)
      trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
      testPredict = model.predict(testX)
      trainPredict = trainPredict.reshape(trainPredict.shape[0])
      testPredict = testPredict.reshape(testPredict.shape[0])
      train_DBN_fitted_Y[i] = trainPredict
      test_DBN_fitted_Y[i]  = testPredict
      i = i + 1
```

Now this loops is very inefficient. Because for example, when it sets, say,  `nb_epoch` = 100, it starts training from `epoch = 1` and finishes at `epoch = 100` like following :

```
Epoch 1/100
0s - loss: 1.9508 - val_loss: 296.7801
.
.
.
Epoch 100/100
0s - loss: 7.6575 - val_loss: 366.2218
```

In the next iteration of loop, where it says `nb_epoch = 200` it starts training from `epoch = 1` again and finishes at `epoch = 200`. But what I want to do is, in this iteration, start training from where it left in the last iteration of the loop i.e. `epoch = 100` and then `epoch = 101` and so on....

How can I modify this loop to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuously calling `fit` is training your model further, starting from the state it was left from the previous call. For it to **not** continue it would have to reset the weights of your model, which `fit` does not do. You are just not seeing that it does that, as it is always starting to count epochs beginning at 1.

So in the end the problem is just that it does not print the correct number of epochs (which you cannot change).

If this is bothering you, you can implement your own `fit` by calling [`model.train_on_batch`](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `initial_epoch` parameter of fit (see [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/))